# Single Player mode in Tic-tac-toe

Tags: javascript, html, css, minimax

I am trying to create a one-player tic-tac-toe game using JavaScript. Following is the code for JavaScript, CSS, and HTML respectively:

```js
const grid = [];
const GRID_LENGTH = 3;
let turn = 'X';

function initializeGrid() {
  for (let colIdx = 0; colIdx < GRID_LENGTH; colIdx++) {
    const tempArray = [];
    for (let rowidx = 0; rowidx < GRID_LENGTH; rowidx++) {
      tempArray.push(0);
    }
    grid.push(tempArray);
  }
}

function getRowBoxes(colIdx) {
  let rowDivs = '';

  for (let rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < GRID_LENGTH; rowIdx++) {
    let additionalClass = 'darkBackground';
    let content = '';
    const sum = colIdx + rowIdx;
    if (sum % 2 === 0) {
      additionalClass = 'lightBackground'
    }
    const gridValue = grid[colIdx][rowIdx];
    if (gridValue === 1) {
      content = '<span class="cross">X</span>';
    } else if (gridValue === 2) {
      content = '<span class="cross">O</span>';
    }
    rowDivs = rowDivs + '<div colIdx="' + colIdx + '" rowIdx="' + rowIdx + '" class="box ' +
      additionalClass + '">' + content + '</div>';
  }
  return rowDivs;
}

function getColumns() {
  let columnDivs = '';
  for (let colIdx = 0; colIdx < GRID_LENGTH; colIdx++) {
    let coldiv = getRowBoxes(colIdx);
    coldiv = '<div class="rowStyle">' + coldiv + '</div>';
    columnDivs = columnDivs + coldiv;
  }
  return columnDivs;
}

function renderMainGrid() {
  const parent = document.getElementById("grid");
  const columnDivs = getColumns();
  parent.innerHTML = '<div class="columnsStyle">' + columnDivs + '</div>';
}

function onBoxClick() {
  var rowIdx = this.getAttribute("rowIdx");
  var colIdx = this.getAttribute("colIdx");
  let newValue = 1;
  grid[colIdx][rowIdx] = newValue;
  renderMainGrid();
  addClickHandlers();
}

function addClickHandlers() {
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  for (var idx = 0; idx < boxes.length; idx++) {
    boxes[idx].addEventListener('click', onBoxClick, false);
  }
}

initializeGrid();
renderMainGrid();
addClickHandlers();
```

```css
.parentTop {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gridTop {
  border-color: "#f44336";
  border: '1px solid red';
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.lightBackground {
  background-color: 00FFFF
}

.columnsStyle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rowStyle {
  display: flex;
}

.darkBackground {
  background-color: F0FFFF
}

.box {
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.cross {
  color: #f90;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1> Tic Tac Toe</h1>
</div>

<div class="parentTop">
  <div class="gridTop">
    <div id="grid">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
```

Here box represents one placeholder for either X or a 0.
We have a 2D array to represent the arrangement of X or O is a grid

```
  0 -> empty box
  1 -> box with X
  2 -> box with O
```

User is playing with Computer so every alternate move should be by Computer
  X -> player
  O -> Computer

I am not able wrap my head around the implementation of the algorithm used for computer (Min-max algorithm is one) in code.

Comment: Are you asking how to apply minimax on your Tic Tac Toe game?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yes please

Comment: In that case, you should ask it on [AI.SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minimax).

Answer (score 0):

traverse it in a loop as column first, and row and then diagonal these are three cases where you have to check consecutive user inputs if first two consecutive user inputs found in any of above case then your program have put their value as third one as apponent